# Overflow-x scroll not working on chrome and working on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to make nav tabs on one line on mobile and allow the user to stroll
it works well on firefox or any browser with -Moz- engine, but it not working at all on chrome or any browser with -WebKit- engine.

screenshots on chrome and firefox

[scrollbar not showing on chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hW7zn.png)
[scrollbar appears on firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lddE7.png)

Here is the element with the problem

I'm using bootstrap 3.3.7

`<ul className="nav nav-tabs cl-light-black d-box overflow-x-scroll"></ul>`

Here is the used CSS to make it on one line and scrollable

```
.d-box {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
}
.overflow-x-scroll {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.cl-light-black {
  color: #2c3f58;
}
```

Comment: You need to set a `width` or `max-width` on the `ul`. If your `ul` grows with the content, then setting `overflow-x` won't do a thing.

Comment: just tried and nothing happens 
I don't know why it doesn't  work on chrome and works on firefox

Comment: Looks like some kind of width issue applied at css level.Try changing widths of menu items or scrollbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the CSS [white space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) property on wrapper element, in your example is `<ul>` tag like the following:

```
ul.overflow-x-scroll {
  ...
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

For each child element, based on your example I think it will be `<li>` tag, make sure that the value of CSS floating property is ***none***:

```
ul.overflow-x-scroll li{
  ...
  float: none;
}
```

Comment: Genius 
your solution solved my problem
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `float: none;` in the list of the menu, like this.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<style>
.d-box {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
}
.overflow-x-scroll {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.cl-light-black {
  color: #2c3f58;
}

.nav-tabs>li {
  float: none;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
  <h3>Tabs</h3>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs cl-light-black d-box overflow-x-scroll">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 8</a></li>

  </ul>
  <br>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried it but when I add float none to the li the nav tabs overflow goes on a new line

Comment: here is the code https://codepen.io/AhmedAdelAlemam/pen/bGERQgm
If you opened the link on chrome the scroll will not work
And if you opened it on firefox it works fine.

Comment: I added the float it's working fine in both chrome and Firefox, https://codepen.io/rajkumar_mp/pen/eYJRaqa

Comment: here is the site i;m working on https://dev.uleague.org/courses/course-23-7a8c8e32-0137-4e80-808f-3399d75aca16 if you or any one could check and try

Comment: if you removed `display: inline-block` in `li` its working with `float:none`

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still has this problem, I found another solution. If you **have not set background color prop in parent element**, maybe that's the problem like mine. When I add that prop, the scrollbar is working now.